# How does re-fertilizer work regarding rocks?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I know that [re-fertilizer](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Re-Fertilizer) will re-grow plants, trees, and rocks that were previously harvested in a small radius from where it's placed.

- Does this work on any type of rock, even oil, obsidian, crystal, etc?
- Is it the **exact** same resource that was previously harvested? Will it yield the same types and amounts of resources? For example, if a crystal gives me a rare mushroom, will it do so again after being refertilized?